# Images not working with Glade?

Tags: application-development, gimp, glade, png

I have this basic Quickly app set up and working fine. I have one image on the first form/view or whatever it is called. I have put the image file in the projectname/data/media/ folder as a png with Gimp. It shows up fine in Glade. I save, then I type:

```
quickly run
```

then it just shows up the icon for file N/A. It says this in the console:

```
Could not load image 'step1.png': Failed to open file '/home/jtp/projectnamme/data/ui/step1.png':
```

Comment: Can you manually open the file, in "Image viewer" or something? Hopefully, you have "saved as" in `gimp` and not changed its extension, as `gimp` does not automatically save in `.png` format.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of specifying your image as `step1.png`, use this (relative) path in place of it:

```
../media/step1.png
```

This should cause it to be accessed in the right place, since `..` represents the parent directory of wherever the application is currently looking (in this case, apparently `/home/jtp/projectnamme/data`), and the actual file is located in `/home/jtp/projectname/media`.